# Вырезать блок регулярным выражением

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте, никак не могу придумать как мне вырезать блок регулярным выражением. Блок начинается на

```
A0B10
тут строки, количество не известно
тут строки, количество не известно
тут строки, количество не известно
тут строки, количество не известно
тут строки, количество не известно
A11B17
тут тоже строки, количество не известно
тут тоже строки, количество не известно
```

т.е. концом блока является начало нового, а конец последнего блока вообще заканчивается, количество блоков тоже не известно

```
AA0
```

Comment: не понятно, какими могут быть эти разделители, но по предоставленным данным думаю решение можно записать как то так:

    print_r(array_map('trim', preg_split('~^[A-B0-9]+$~m', $text)));

Answer (score 1):

Приведенный ниже код будет корректно работать только если названия блоков будут уникальными.
Пустые блоки корректно обрабатываются.

**Суть идеи:**
1) развернуть текст в массив, где название блока это ключ, а строки после него - значение;
2) исключить из этого массива блок с заданным ключом;
3) свернуть массив обратно в текст;

**Реализация:**

```
function unsetTextBlock($block_title, $text) {

    $data = collectTextBlocks($text);

    if (array_key_exists($block_title, $data)) {
        unset($data[$block_title]);
        $data = removeLastEol($data);   
    }

    return stringifyTextBlocks($data);

}

function collectTextBlocks($text) {

    $pattern = '~^[A-Z][A-Z0-9]+~m';
    preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $match);

    $keys = array_shift($match);
    $values = preg_split($pattern, $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

    $keys_total = count($keys);
    $values_total = count($values);

    while ($keys_total - $values_total > 0) {
        $values[] = '';
        ++$values_total;
    }

    return array_combine($keys, $values);

}

function stringifyTextBlocks($array) {

    foreach ($array as $k => $v) {          
        $string .= $k . $v;
    }

    return $string;

}

function removeLastEol($array) {

    $segment = array_slice($array, -1, 1);
    array_pop($array);

    foreach ($segment as $k => $v) {
        $array[$k] = preg_replace('~[\r\n]*$~', '', $v);            
    }

    return $array;

}
```

**Использование:**

```
$text = 'A0B10
string A
string B
string C
A11B17
string D
AA0
string E
AA1
AA2
string F';

$result_1 = unsetTextBlock('AA0', $text);
$result_2 = unsetTextBlock('A11B17', $text);
```

**Результат:**
[image: Результат]

---

"-" — просто индикатор того, что строки идентичны и в конце нет переносов строк.